# Is it possible to load weights only from a saved model file in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a saved trained model file in Keras which was saved using `model.save()`. Is it possible to load only the weights of the model from that file? Because I am getting an error when I try to load the model as a whole.

Comment: Please share us the code you've tried and also the error you got. Generally yes. It's possible to load only the weights.

Comment: I already have a trained h5 model file of some pre-defined architecture. I just want to load weights from it. It's not possible for me to share the architecture of my model.

Comment: Have you tried `model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')` for a previously saved HDF5 file using `model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')`?

Comment: In order to load weights, you should save the weights using `model.save_weights()` and then declare the model and use `model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')`. This suits you?

Comment: I do not have a `model_weights.h5` file. I have a `model.h5` file. I only want to load the weights from it though.

Comment: @Viktor1903 What error did you get when try to load the entire model?

Comment: This is the error I get when I try to load the model: `ValueError: An operation has \`None\` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.`

Comment: This is an old problem but I have the solution to a similar problem with custom layers without from_config and get_config in the layers. Apparently it is indeed possible to just redefine the model and load the weights with model.load_weights from the model saved with model.save_model.

Comment: An answer to this question would be useful when we have a CNN model and the input shape changed between train and test time.